# Elm: Partial Function Application and Let

Tags: elm, let

The [Beginning Elm - Let Expression](http://elmprogramming.com/let-expression.html) page builds on the previous page, but it doesn't cover how to update the main function, written in forward function notation, which was:

```
main =
    time 2 3
        |> speed 7.67
        |> escapeEarth 11
        |> Html.text
```

to include the new fuelStatus parameter.

The compiler complains about a type mismatch, which is correct, as escapeEarth now has a third argument, which is a string.

As stated on that site "The forward function application operator takes the result from the previous expression and passes it as the last argument to the next function application."

In other words, how do I write this:

```
Html.text (escapeEarth 11 (speed 7.67 (time 2 3)) "low")
```

using forward notation?

Also, why doesn't this print "Land on droneship", along with "Stay in orbit"? It only prints "Stay in orbit":

```
module Playground exposing (..)

import Html


escapeEarth velocity speed fuelStatus =
    let
        escapeVelocityInKmPerSec =
            11.186

        orbitalSpeedInKmPerSec =
            7.67

        whereToLand fuelStatus =
            if fuelStatus == "low" then
                "Land on droneship"
            else
                "Land on launchpad"
    in
    if velocity > escapeVelocityInKmPerSec then
        "Godspeed"
    else if speed == orbitalSpeedInKmPerSec then
        "Stay in orbit"
    else
        "Come back"


speed distance time =
    distance / time


time startTime endTime =
    endTime - startTime


main =
    Html.text (escapeEarth 11 (speed 7.67 (time 2 3)) "low")
```

Comment: `whereToLand` doesn't "print" because it is not returned from the function. It is defined in the let expression, but not used in the expression.

Comment: Thanks Tyler, I see my mistake, the second else should have been else whereToLand fuelStatus, instead of else "Come back"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you need is

```
main =
    time 2 3
        |> speed 7.67
        |> \spd -> escapeEarth 11 spd "low"
        |> Html.text
```

In other words you define a little anonymous function to insert the value correctly. You may want to look at whether the escapeEarth function should be defined with a different order.

An alternative if you love 'point free' would be

```
main =
    time 2 3
        |> speed 7.67
        |> flip (escapeEarth 11) "low"
        |> Html.text
```

Some would argue that this is less clear though

As for your second question you have defined functions in your let statement but never actually used it

Comment: Three different answers, each a valid way to solve the problem. Thank you very much Simon. Could you please have a look at my second point about why only one string prints instead of two.